# Calculate values from json file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a script

```
#!/bin/bash

#create path to redirect output.json to same directory as output.txt
path=$(dirname $1)

#create variables for name line, test lines and result line
firstline=$(cat $1 | head -n +1 | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
testname=$(echo $firstline)

tests=$(cat $1 | tail -n +3 | head -n -2)

results=$(cat $1 | tail -n1)

#create main JSON variable
json=$(jq -n --arg tn "$testname" '{testname:$tn,tests:[],summary:{}}')

#test's names, status, duration and updating JSON variable
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $tests
do
    if [[ $i == not* ]]
    then
        stat=false
    else
        stat=true
    fi

    if [[ $i =~ expecting(.+?)[0-9] ]]
    then
        var=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        name=${var%,*}
    fi

    if [[ $i =~ [0-9]*ms ]]
    then
        test_duration=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi

    json=$(echo $json | jq \
        --arg na "$name" \
        --arg st "$stat" \
        --arg dur "$test_duration" \
        '.tests += [{name:$na,status:$st|test("true"),duration:$dur}]')
done

#final success, failed, rating, duration and finishing JSON variable

IFS=$'\n'
for l in $results
do
    if [[ $l =~ [0-9]+ ]]
    then
        success=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi

    if [[ $l =~ ,.[0-9]+ ]]
    then
        v=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        failed=${v:2}
    fi

    if [[ $l =~ [0-9]+.[0-9]+% ]] || [[ $l =~ [0-9]+% ]]
    then
        va=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        rating=${va%%%}
    fi

    if [[ $l =~ [0-9]*ms ]]
    then
        duration=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi

    json=$(echo $json | jq \
                --arg suc "$success" \
                --arg fa "$failed" \
                --arg rat "$rating" \
            --arg dur "$duration" \
            '.summary += {success:$suc|tonumber,failed:$fa|tonumber,rating:$rat|tonumber,duration:$dur}')
done

#redirect variable's output to file
echo $json | jq "." > $path"/output.json"
```

Output.json looks like:

```json
{
  "testname": "Behave test",
  "tests": [
    {
      "name": "some text",
      "status": true,
      "duration": "7ms"
    },
    {
      "name": "some text",
      "status": false,
      "duration": "27ms"
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "success": 1,
    "failed": 1,
    "rating": 50,
    "duration": "34ms"
  }
}
```

Output is much more than in my example above. My question is, how I can calculate **"summary"** values and put it to json?

- "success" - tests with status true;
- "failed" - tests with status false;
- "rating" - success / total, and it can be float or int
- "duration" - sum of "duration" field

I will be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adds (or replaces) a `.summary` field which is calculated by `reduce`ing the `.tests` array to an object, initialized as `{success: 0, failed: 0}`. For each array item, either `.success` or `.failed` is incremented, depending on the current array item's boolean `.state` field. The `.rating` field is incremented unconditionally, thus counting the total number of items which is later used to calculate the true rating. As for the duration, the array item's `.duration` field is converted into a number by chopping off the `ms` suffix, and added to the summary's (numeric) `.duration` field. After the reduction, the rating is corrected by dividing the the success count by it (and multiplied by `100` for convenience). The `? // 0` part catches division by zero issues, in case the `.tests` array was empty. Finally, the `.duration` field is re-equipped with the `ms` suffix.

```bash
.summary = (reduce .tests[] as $t ({success: 0, failed: 0};
  (if $t.status then .success else .failed end, .rating) += 1
  | .duration += ($t.duration | rtrimstr("ms") | tonumber)
) | .rating = (100 * (.success / .rating)? // 0) | .duration |= "\(.//0)ms")
```

```json
{
  "testname": "Behave test",
  "tests": [
    {
      "name": "some text",
      "status": true,
      "duration": "7ms"
    },
    {
      "name": "some text",
      "status": false,
      "duration": "27ms"
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "success": 1,
    "failed": 1,
    "rating": 50,
    "duration": "34ms"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/21KEcfHVwOG)

Comment: Thank you very much! Сan you explain this construction?

Comment: @lunnyj I have added some explanations.

Comment: I have a strange behaviour, when I paste .summary in my script, the values has been swapped. 
    "summary": {
    "failed": 2,
    "rating": 71.42857142857143,
    "duration": "132ms",
    "success": 5
  }
What I do wrong?

Comment: @lunnyj The JSON data format has no order on object fields, only on array items. This means that a JSON processor (like jq) may output fields in any order, it is still regarded as the equivalent document. With the current implementations of jq you *can*, however, force the ordering by re-setting it explicitly (here, add `| {success, failed, rating, duration}` **before** the last closing parenthesis ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/e-r9i1qmWCN))), but beware that this is just a side-effect which jq may change at some point, and other tools in your post-processing may not adhere to this either.